# How to access onfocus event from iframe (cross-origin)?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have html app that uses `onfocus` event. It's working perfectly when switching tabs of browser.

Now, when I load that app as an `iframe` in another html page, it's not working because the `iframe` is not focused when switching tabs. How to access `onfocus` event from `iframe` **without modification of top level code**.

*The `iframe` and page that loads iframe are not from same origin.*

```
if (!window.parent.frames.length) {
    window.onfocus = function () {
        // do smth
    };
} else {
    // ???
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimum code to show how it is setup.

Comment: I see that the iframe and parent document are on different origins. Do you control the content in both documents/origins?

Comment: Well this is minimum code. 
I was doing some animations based on events (socket). They should be real-time animations, so I needed a queue. When switching tabs, queue should be cleaned and it was working if app wasn't an `iframe`. But when it is an `iframe`, I couldn't clean queue because `onfocus` event wont fire up.

@Amber de Black answer might be solution for me.

Comment: @J.Kovacevic Try out the answer I provided that uses `postMessage` to pass the parent `onfocus` event into the `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Visibility API. It allows you to detect when user leaves and returns to the tab.

At moment when I'm writing this post - this feature supported by 90% of browser:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility

Sample code for iframe page:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    var time = new Date();

    if (document.hidden) {
            console.log(time + ' the user has left tab');
    } else {
            console.log(time + ' the user has returned to the tab');
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you control both the parent and the iframe pages' content then you could use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass the parent's `onfocus` event into the iframe.

Here is an example:

## `<iframe>` content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        // Function to call when receiving a `postMessage`
        function listener(event){
            if (event.data === 'focus-event') {
                document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += '<h2>Parent is in focus</h2>';
            }
        };

        // `postMessage` event listener
        window.addEventListener('message', listener, false);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Child</h1>
    </body>
</html>;
```

## Parent content:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
    iframe.postMessage('focus-event', '*');
}, false);
```

This will make it so that every time the parent window receives a `focus` event it will post that message to the iframe.

Here is a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/wagifom/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Yes, that is also one solution. I'm using `postMessage` to send some events from `iframe` (my app) to parent frame and that part is optional, it just provides some extra data to parent frame. I used @amber solution, because app will be implemented like plugin and sometimes I wont be able to pass parent's `onfocus` event to iframe.